# how can i map a subdomain to a container port using traefik 2 and docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, port, subdomain, traefik

I have 2 subdomains, let's call them `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`.  I am using docker-compose to spin up services `foo` and `bar`. I would like to map each service (container `foo` and `bar`) to the subdomains using traefik 2.x.  For example, visiting `foo.example.com` on port 80 will forward to container foo listening on 8100.  Bar follows a similar pattern, `bar.example.com` will trigger container bar via port 8200.  Here is some of my code so far, but I'm struggling to connect these dots.

```
service:
  foo:
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      8100:80
  bar:
    networks:
      - default
      - bar
    ports:
      8200:80
```

I'm using the following labels for foo:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.services.foo.loadbalancer.server.port=8100"
  - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
  - "traefik.http.routers.foo.rule=Host(`foo.example.com`)"
```

and here are the labels for bar:

```
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.bar-bazboo.redirectregex.permanent=true"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.bar-bazboo.redirectregex.regex=^https://(.*)/.well-known/(baz|fizz)boo"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.bar-bazboo.redirectregex.replacement=https://$${1}/remote.php/boo/"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.bar-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar-http.entrypoints=web"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar-http.rule=Host(`bar.example.com`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar-http.middlewares=bar-https@docker"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar.entrypoints=web-secure"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar.rule=Host(`bar.example.com`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar.middlewares=bar-bazboo@docker"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar.tls=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.bar.tls.certresolver=le"
- "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true"
```

and networks:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
  traefik:
    internal: true
  bar:
```

EDIT: bar currently doesn't have any port mappings for debugging, and network bar is exclusively for 2 and only 2 services.

I can help with providing additional information.  Thanks.

Comment: try to add also network tag inside each service

Comment: try to add bar network into foo service

Comment: network foo is needed by a different service, `foo-gaz`.  both foo and bar are on the default network and run fine.